# List IP/MAC/names of local network devices python

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

I have this very useful Android app called "Fing", which lists all the devices on my local network. This includes their ip addresses, MAC addresses, names and producer (Apple, Intel, ...).

As Android apps have very limited possibilities (only network requests), this should also be doable from a python script.

How can I list all available devices on my local network with python 3, if possible platform independent and without root privileges?

Comment: Ok, after some research I can speculate that Fing does something like ping every IP address on the network and than get the corresponding MAC addresses from the /proc/net/arp file. Of course, this only works on Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

python-nmap is a python library which helps in using nmap port scanner.
It allows to easilly manipulate nmap scan results and will be a perfect
tool for systems administrators who want to automatize scanning task
and reports. It also supports nmap script outputs.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap